# Can't get slideshow to transition smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little stuck at the moment, I'm not sure how I would get these images in my slideshow at the bottom to transition smoothly, I'm new to coding in general, and know very little about javascript and CSS. I do know the foundations of HTML though. 
If anyone could offer some assitance that would be much appreciated.

I've pasted my code down below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> EVOLUTION </title>
 <style type="text/css">
        body {
          background-image:url('backgroundimagebase.jpg');
          
     background-size:cover;
    
    background-attachment: fixed
    
    </style>
 <style>
 .mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>
<style>
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

img + img { opacity: 0; }
</style>
<style>
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

img + img { opacity: 0; }
</style>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<!--slideshow stuff-->

<!--image headings-->


<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
  <a href="file:///C:/Users/Harrison%20Gobey/Desktop/College%20Work/Unit%2028/website/projectwebsite3.html"><img src="pcexclusives.jpg" alt="pcexclusives" style="width:100%" height="768" width="1366"></a>
  <div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-white">Check out our new range of PC exclusives!
  </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
  <a href="https://www.polygon.com/2018/6/14/17465314/battlefield-5-women-historical-accuracy-reddit-banned"><img  src="battlefieldV.jpg" style="width:100%" height="768" width="1366"></a>
  <div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-white">
    Battlefield V panned by fans for historical inaccuracy
  </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
  <a href="http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/elders-scrolls-6-trailer-release-date-2993132"><img src="bethesdaes6.jpg" style="width:100%" height="768" width="1366"></a>
  <div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-white">
    Bethesda officially announce Elder Scrolls 6 at E3 2018
  </div>
</div>


<!--image indicator-->
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <div class="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
</script>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
</script>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question is *almost* good; you've provided an example! However, we would really <3 it if you could create a [**minimal**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, which would make our jobs way easier! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've cut the code down to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. One is that there is no opening `body` tag, also, the css for the body has no closing bracket. There is duplication in your css styling and also in your javascript code, you redeclare the same variable three times. It should only be declared once, and then re-used. Another error in your javascript was where you were calling the showDivs function. I moved this line into the carousel function.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9gv8s2h/) which I hope you find of help (pix may not accurate but do remember that locally stored files can only be called from your own computer - better to specify sources from server)

Rachel

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
  showDivs(slideIndex);
}


function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}




function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-white";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('backgroundimagebase.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.w3-left,
.w3-right,
.w3-badge {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.w3-badge {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

img+img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--slideshow stuff-->

<!--image headings-->

<body>

  <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <a href="file:///C:/Users/Harrison%20Gobey/Desktop/College%20Work/Unit%2028/website/projectwebsite3.html"><img src="pcexclusives.jpg" alt="pcexclusives" style="width:100%" height="768" width="1366"></a>
    <div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-white">Check out our new range of PC exclusives!
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <a href="https://www.polygon.com/2018/6/14/17465314/battlefield-5-women-historical-accuracy-reddit-banned"><img src="battlefieldV.jpg" style="width:100%" height="768" width="1366"></a>
    <div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-white">
      Battlefield V panned by fans for historical inaccuracy
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <a href="http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/elders-scrolls-6-trailer-release-date-2993132"><img src="bethesdaes6.jpg" style="width:100%" height="768" width="1366"></a>
    <div class="w3-display-topmiddle w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-white">
      Bethesda officially announce Elder Scrolls 6 at E3 2018
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--image indicator-->
  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <div class="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
      <div class="w3-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
      <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
      <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
      <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```